# Update pagination according to filtered data

Tags: angularjs

How to update pagination according to filtered data in Angularjs.

html Code.

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search">


<tr ng-repeat="application in applications=application | filter:search | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*itemsPerPage |limitTo:itemsPerPage">
```

controller.js

```
$scope.$watch('search',function (term) {

                            $scope.applications = $filter('startFrom')($scope.application,term);
                            //
                            $scope.size = $scope.applications.length;
                            $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.size / $scope.itemsPerPage);
                        $scope.currentPage = 1;


                    }, true);
```

filter.

```
module.filter('startFrom', function () {
    return function (input, start) {
        if (input) {
            start = +start;
            return input.slice(start);
        }
        return [];
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search function:

```
  $scope.search = function () {
        $scope.filteredList = 
       filteredListService.searched($scope.allItems, $scope.searchText);

        if ($scope.searchText == '') {
            $scope.filteredList = $scope.allItems;
        }
        $scope.pagination(); 
    }
```

Calculate Total Number of Pages based on Search Result

```
 $scope.pagination = function () {
        $scope.ItemsByPage = filteredListService.paged( $scope.filteredList, $scope.pageSize );         
    };

    $scope.setPage = function () {
        $scope.currentPage = this.n;
    };

    $scope.firstPage = function () {
        $scope.currentPage = 0;
    };

    $scope.lastPage = function () {
        $scope.currentPage = $scope.ItemsByPage.length - 1;
    };
```

Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ilovenagpur/wPnxy/) example for pagination with filter so that you can use it and modify it for your requirements.